# Regular Expression in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Well, I Will developer a close blog in laravel, this blog needs take the name of the people who has logged!

I wanna replace for example `{[userName]}` for `auth->user()->name()`

I Will write `{[userName]}` in my text editor Ane show the name of user logged in my view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think just use `str_replace`

eg:

```
$input = "My name is [USERNAME]";

echo str_replace("[USERNAME]", auth->user()->name(), $input);
```